# Turn off spell-checking in Xcode Commit comments

Tags: xcode, spell-checking

Does anyone know how to turn off spell checking in Xcode's commit comments area? It's very annoying to always have to correct the correcter when typing in my notes. For example whenever I enter an iVar's name or a method name the spell checker will decide that I have spelt it wrong and make some ludicrous guess at what it should be.

Answer (score 3):

Right-click in the comments area.  There's a Spelling and Grammar menu. You can uncheck 
"Correct Spelling Automatically", but I can't figure out how to make the setting persist.  It goes back to the default on the next commit. (Using Xcode 5.1.1.)

Comment: Yeah, thanks @GraniteRobert, that's what I'm getting too. It's too much of a pain to keep setting it and I was looking for a permanent change.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this by turning spell check off globally for my Mac.

**System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text**

If that's an acceptable solution then it may help anyone reading this.

Answer (score 1):

Click on Edit -> Format -> Spelling and Grammer and click on Show Spelling and Grammer. If it is checked it will be unchecked. Or Edit -> Format -> Spelling and Grammer and click on Check Spelling While Typing to have the same effect.